# Hide console of Windows Application

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt, console, hide

I have a Qt application, and when I run this application, there is a console opening behind it. In development it is nice because i see debug outputs on the console, but when I want to give this executable to the customer there should be no console window.
how do I hide it?

(I am using Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: Best way is to make a QT Project and use QVTKWidget.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It sounds like your linker configuration is incorrect.  Right-click the project, Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem setting.  Make sure "Windows" is selected, not "Console".

And, change main() to WinMain().

Comment: is there a difference between main() and WinMain()?

Comment: You may also set the entry point of the project to standard `main()` in Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry point

Comment: The problem is that when I turn the program in `Windows` it doesn't terminate, even if I fix the `main`/`WinMain` issue.

Comment: @JanTuroň How? What option do we put in that field? It's a string field and I've tried a wide variety of solutions, none of which work.

Comment: @NicHartley back then in 2008 it should be a selectbox. Perharps there are other settings in config. Could you ask another question and provide step by step setup to reproduce that?

Answer (score 160):

In the project build linker options set

```
/SUBSYSTEM:windows
/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup
```

Or use the following *#pragma* in the source file with the `int main(...)`

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Comment: Imo the best and to-the-point answer, dealing with both the subsystem part and the different entry points part. Small unicode hint: if you compile with unicode and have wmain as opposed to main, comment should be "/ENTRY:wmainCRTStartup".

Comment: @Cray: WCHAR is not Unicode. If you're using real Unicode with the appropriate libraries like ICU, normal mainCRTStrartup works just fine.

Comment: Sure, however I was talking about the compiler option (ie, "compile with unicode"). They are actually calling it "Use Unicode Character Set".

Comment: This solution worked for me and my OpenGL application. I started the project months ago as a console application, using the console window for early debugging. Starting the project again as a windows application and pasting all of the files over, as well as re-entering all of the library dependencies just seemed tedious.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: Pro-Tipp: If you need a console later on for debugging you can use AllocConsole http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In VS 2010 the pragma didn't work for me. I had to set the two settings through project properties, removed _CONSOLE from the preprocessor. Then I rebuilt, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. E.g. if you are developing with CMake on Windows, this is the only option. Also, it is portable to other windowing systems, such as GLFW, SDL, ...

Comment: This helped out very much!

Comment: Worked for me. Qt6, Win10, MSVC2019, amd64 build.

Answer (score 24):

You can get rid of the console by calling:

```
FreeConsole();
```

Comment: You'll have to `#include <Windows.h>` for that

Answer (score 14):

i use that method and it worked

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
```

Comment: If you start the program from command line the command line will disappear. `FreeConsole` does not have that issue.

Answer (score 10):

Next solution ;)

Env: WixXP x64, msvs 2008, Qt v4.5.3

1. Set Projects settings/Configuration properties/Linker/System/SubSystem = Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

   But For x64 there is linker error:
   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain referenced in function _WinMainCRTStartup"
   To avoid it
2. Replace the following code:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        // your code*
   }
   ```

   by

   ```
   int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char*, int nShowCmd)
   {
       int argc = 0;
       QApplication app( argc, 0 );
    }
   ```

It works fine for both - Win32 and x64 platforms.

Comment: This method will prevent the program from getting parameters from the command line. Very, very bad idea. -1. If you want to do it correctly, tokenize the string you receive fin the third parameter of WinMain. And yes, there are plenty of Windows programs that interpret command line parameters. For example the "Printing" context menu in Windows Explorer starts a program with command line parameters.

Comment: datenwolf, They are still there using __argv and __argc macros (at least in MSVC) or GetCommandLine/CommandLineToArgv winapi function.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Many thank :))

Answer (score 6):

May be the better option will be not to simply remove (as Andy M suggested) but edit *.pro file adding something like

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    CONFIG *= console
} 
else {
    CONFIG -= console
}
```

In debug you can see console window but not in release. I like it. =)

Answer (score 6):

If you use **Properties**->**Linker**->**System**->**SubSystem** | **Windows**

And get a linker error.

You can look at **Linker**->**Advanced**-> **Entry Point**

and set the value to the name of your "main" function.

That is your Entry Point becomes, main, if your main function is a "main".

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to check the presence of the following line in your .PRO file :

```
CONFIG += console
```

If you can find it, remove it ! It should fix your issue !

Hope it helps !

Comment: The actual Visual Studio project is created using the configuration parameters in the QMake project file, so this could very well be the cause.

Comment: Erm, in the VCProj properties, maybe by going in Links Edition, System and finally Subsystem... Try putting the value "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)"... I'm not really sure you can do it like that tho...

Comment: I quickly tested in one of my application and for some obscure reason, i need to add the following lib :

c:\...\Qt\4.6.0-vs2008\lib\qtmain.lib

in VCProj Properties-> Links Edition -> Entry -> Additionnal Dependencies

Comment: And it looks like it's the final solution :)

http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-12/thread00170-0.html

Answer (score 2):

For those of you editing the .vcxproj directly, you want to add a `SubSystem` with the value `Windows` to your `Link` `ItemDefinitionGroup` as follows:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Link>
    <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
  </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `Projects --> Run` and uncheck `Run in terminal` checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If all of the properties settings not working above, maybe check to delete 'return app.exec' and 'system("pause")' would help

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    CONFIG *= console
} 
else {
    CONFIG -= console
}
```

I needed to run an exe to monitor a file using `QFileSystemWatcher` so I used this:

```
CONFIG -= console
```

Answer (score -1):

step 1:- Set Properties->Linker->System->SubSystem   is "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)"
Step 2:- Linker->Advanced-> Entry Point  "main"

Comment: Step 2 skips CRT initialization. The results of doing so are dire.