# Removing the command prompt

Tags: c++

In C++, what is the standard way to remove the command prompt, without using WinMain()? This is hopefully a simple question. I am using MSVC.

Comment: Do you mean the whole console window? If so, that the way.

Comment: If by standard your mean in the C++ standard, theres no "standard way"

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139637/hide-console-of-windows-application    note there are methods to dynamically remove the console window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to set `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` (as opposed to `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`), you can do this in GUI (right click the project, properties, Linker, System, Subsystem).

Then you have to either

1. define `WinMain`, or
2. define `main` and set the entry point to `mainCRTStartup` (properties, Linker, Advanced, entry point).

Comment: Good, it worked. Is there a solution that will not require me to change any project settings. Like a preprocessor or macro, ect...

Comment: using `#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")` you could do the same for the other options. Check the `pragma` preprocessor.