# OpenGL and VS2010 unresolved external

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, windows-7, glut, unresolved-external

I want to use GLUT to simplify my code and work.

I'm using windows 7 (64 bit) and Visual Studio 2010. I did everything like in [this tutorial](http://logs.tobinelectronics.com/installing-glut-in-windows-visual-studio-2010/) and still can't compile my code... I get these errors:

```
Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals <path>
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartuL
```

The code I use:

```
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GL/glut.h> 

void display (void) {  
   glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
   glLoadIdentity(); 

   glFlush(); 
}  

int main (int argc, char **argv) {  
   glutInit(&argc, argv); 
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE); 
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100); 
   glutCreateWindow ("Your first OpenGL Window");  

   glutDisplayFunc(display); /

   glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

Does someone know whats the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your created **Windows** application instead of a *Console* one.
See the pic below for how to change/choose the  Windows subsystem

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! That helped! Love you :)) However now when i run the program the window shows up with the console window in background... can i edit it somehow that the console won't apear?

Comment: Try plugging this to your main() preamble                           HWND hWnd = ::GetConsoleWindow();
::ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );

Comment: @ShmilTheCat: While this works, it's not the best solution. A much nicer solution I did describe at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368

Comment: @L3M0L: Another way to get rid of the console window: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368