# Error compiling an empty CUDA project

Tags: windows, cuda, nvidia

There is an error while compiling an **empty** Cuda 5.0 project:

1*) Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

2*) Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup

When I edit additional dependencies in PropertyPages>Linker>Input as : cuda.lib;cudart.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;‌​advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;‌​%(AdditionalDependencies)

How can I resolve it? PLEASE note: I don't have a GPU in my system but I was told that it does not matter and that I can still code some things in CUDA

Comment: Every application must have a `main()` subroutine to link. Yours doesn't. This has nothing to with CUDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add empty `main` function and make sure you work w/ a *Console* application and not w/ a window one (please take a look also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440476/opengl-and-vs2010-unresolved-external/15440674#comment21849343_15440674))