# Command Prompt Opens With OpenGL Program

Tags: opengl, cmd, command-prompt

Why does the windows command prompt open whenever I run my OpenGL program?

Answer (score 6):

This is nothing specific with OpenGL, but with the framework you use. Most likely you're using GLUT, for which the tutorials use the program entry function `main`. The default subsystem for programs using `main` (in contrast to `WinMain`) opens a console window when started. You can get rid of it using the method I showed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368

---

If you're using Visual C++ in the project build linker options set

```
/SUBSYSTEM:windows
/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup
```

Or use the following *#pragma* in the source file with the `int main(...)`

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

If using a GNU toolchain use the following additional linker flags to set the subsystem. No need to change the entry function.

```
LDFLAGS += --subsystem windows
```

Comment: When I compile my program, it says: "warning: ignoring pragma comment [-Wunknown-pragmas]"

Comment: @JakeSumrican: Let me guess: You're not using Visual C++? Sorry, I should have added, that the instructions were specific to Microsoft's toolchain. In case you're using a GNU toolchain you must use linker options. See my answer update, I'll add in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Visual Studio linker configuration setting that can be modified.

In order to disable the console window from appearing during your application's run-time, do the following:

1. Right-click the project
2. Go to Properties -> Linker -> System ->SubSystem setting
3. Ensure that "Windows" is selected and not "Console".