Hide Console from .BAS compiled into .exe code
I'm developing an application manager to handle the execution of some legacy code written in .bas files. The application is being developed in Java/Kotlin and is accessed via a web service. The .bas files are compiled into .exe files using qb64. When the web service is called, it triggers the manager to execute a series of functions in a specific order.
The problem I'm facing is that these .exe files constantly pop up console windows on the server, which is causing issues. Additionally, sometimes the console windows steal focus, causing the execution to get stuck.
Is there a way to compile these .bas files into .exe files that do not open console windows? Alternatively, is there a way to run these .exe files silently from my Java/Kotlin application to prevent the console windows from appearing?
I've tried running the .exe files using commands like:
shell
Copy code
start /min cmd /c d:/Teste.exe
but this approach still results in the console windows appearing.
Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Hiding the console window can be done in C, C++ or C#. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430801/13963086. So perhaps you can use JNI to do it.
