# How can one create a gui application without a console?

Tags: windows, user-interface, ocaml

How can one create or compile a GUI application under Windows without a console?
I have already searched the Internet, but I didn't find anything useful.  I would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

```
(* ocamlc -I +labltk labltk.cma gui.ml -o gui.exe *)

open Tk ;;

let top = openTk () ;;
Wm.title_set top "Application 1" ;;
Wm.geometry_set top "200x500";;

let blue = Button.create ~text:"Blue" top ;;
let red = Button.create ~text:"Red" top ;;
pack [blue ; red];;

let mylist = Listbox.create ~selectmode:`Multiple top
let _ = Listbox.insert
    ~index:`End
    ~texts:["Mozart";"Chopin";"Beethoven";"Verdi";"Bizet"]
    mylist ;;
pack [mylist];;

let _ = Printexc.print mainLoop ();;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to pass '-subsystem windows' to the linker; and probably '-custom', because ocamlrun.exe is a console application:

```
ocamlc -I +labltk labltk.cma gui.ml -custom -cclib -subsystem -cclib windows -o gui.exe
```

Comment: cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\DOCUME~1\SA\LOCALS~1\Temp\camlprim8e3098.c
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/SA/LOCALS~1/Temp/camlprim8
e3098.c
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
** Fatal error: Cannot find file "libws2_32"
File "gui.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while building custom runtime system

Answer (score 2):

I'm mostly an OS X / Unix / Linux programmer myself, but you might try this other SO page:

[Hide console of Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139637/hide-console-of-windows-application)

The key factors appear to be linker options and the entry point name.