# OpenGL SuperBible Example without Console /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, command-line-arguments

The OpenGl SuperBible Examples are shipped with the Property "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS", which eliminates the console window, if i am trying to use "/SUBSYSTEM:Console" to start with console i get the error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

However the main function is redirected by the example files with

```
DECLARE_MAIN(singlepoint_app)
```

In this file DECLARE_MAIN is declared: [Link](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/include/sb6.h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you're trying to do is the reverse of what I described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368

Your code examples use `WinMain` for the entry point but changing to the console subsystem by defaults uses the `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` entry point as defined by the C standard.

So you can use this

```
/SUBSYSTEM:console
/ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup
```

Or use the following #pragma in the source file with the `WinMain`

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:console /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup")
```