# Linker error regarding OpenGL program (_WinMain@16 referenced)

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

Compiling an OpenGL program gives the following linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced
```

Display function

```
void display(void)
{
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);    
   glRotatef ((GLfloat) shoulder, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   glPushMatrix();
   glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
   glutWireCube (1.0);
   glPopMatrix();

   glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glRotatef ((GLfloat) elbow, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   glPushMatrix();
   glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
   glutWireCube (1.0);

   glPopMatrix();
   glPopMatrix();
   glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Window resize handler

```
void reshape (int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(65.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0, 20.0);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glTranslatef (0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
}
```

Keyboard input handler

```
void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
      case 's':   /*  s key rotates at shoulder  */
         shoulder = (shoulder + 5) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;

      case /*`*/'S':
         shoulder = (shoulder - 5) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;

      case /*`*/'e':  /*  e key rotates at elbow  */
         elbow = (elbow + 5) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;

      case /*`*/'E':
         elbow = (elbow - 5) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;

      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of sanely reformatting your code and inferring the question you probably have from your question title. Next time please properly format your code, describe your problem and write a meaningful title.

Answer (score 0):

The error `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced` means, that your program lacks the process entry function `WinMain`. There are two possible causes:

#### Possibility 1

Your program has a entry function `main` but you're compiling for a target subsystem `Windows`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/524368 for details. Essentially you have to specify a different startup function.

Either

```
/SUBSYSTEM:windows
/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup
```

Or

```
/SUBSYSTEM:console
```

#### Possiblity 2

Your code lacks an entry point function. You need at least either a function `main` or `WinMain`, together with the appropriate linker subsystem and entry settings. Without such a function provided you get this error.